# Did İyi Parti-Demokrat Parti enter parliament despite having less than 10% of the vote? How?

Tags: election, turkey

In [Turkish parliamentary elections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electoral_system_of_Turkey), a threshold of 10% applies for any party to enter parliament.  At the [2018 general election](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turkish_general_election,_2018#Parliamentary_election), İyi Parti-Demokrat Parti reportedly reached 9.96%, yet also reportedly enters parliament with 43 seats.  Did İyi Parti-Demokrat Parti enter Turkish parliament despite having less than 10% of the vote?  How is it possible if the 10% threshold (still) applies?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In 2017, the Turkish Parliament passed a law allowing alliances to be formed to jointly pass that 10% threshold. The IYI party is part of the [National Alliance](https://www.aljazeera.com/news/2018/06/turkey-opposition-alliance-necessity-180620094842617.html) with the CHP and the Saadet Party. The alliance as a whole easily passed the 10% threshold. This does not mean that the parties are merged or have to vote together--in fact they have said that now that elections are over the alliance is [dissolved](https://www.nytimes.com/reuters/2018/07/04/world/europe/04reuters-turkey-politics-opposition.html). This is distinct from a strategy Kurdish parties have used in the past: running [independent](https://www.brookings.edu/blog/markaz/2015/04/03/the-kurds-will-decide-turkeys-fate/) candidates who don't need to reach 10%.

Comment: What a strange law.

Comment: The AKP passed it because they were worried that their allies, the MHP, would not exceed the 10% threshold. The two parties entered into an alliance together following the passage.

Comment: That makes sense.  I was thinking that it had the feel of a very targeted "bend the rules for political gain" change, and I guess it was.

Comment: Hmm, but Saadet Partisi with 1.36% of the vote still has 0 seats, is there still a (smaller) threshold for parties within alliances?

Comment: BTW, great irony that AKP passed a law because they were worried that their partners wouldn't pass the 10% threshold, and now it has actually benefited the opposition Millet İttifakı more than it has the government Cumhur İttifakı! (And AKP now depends on MHP for parliamentary majority)

Comment: @gerrit I can't confirm for sure, but I believe that Saadet Partisi won no seats because they didn't have strong enough performances in any district to merit a seat. As part of the alliance, they put their candidates lower on the list in some districts. I don't believe they were unable to win any seats, I think they just happened to win none.

Comment: @gerrit Eremi is right. [Saadet Party's votes](http://www.hurriyet.com.tr/secim/24-haziran-2018-secimleri/saadet-secim-sonuclari) are distributed to all electoral districts very uniformly. The highest rate they achieved is 3.3% (Bayburt province), which is not enough for a seat in any province except Istanbul.